# What could be causing my Vue.js fetch API code to not display fake users as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, fetch-api

```
<body class="container bg-warning">
    <h1>
        Usuários de Teste via REST
    </h1>
    <p>
        referência ao site reqres.in responsável por fornecer os dados de teste,
        no formato JSON, de forma gratuita
    </p>
    <div id="usuarios" class=" container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card col-3 p-2 m-3" v-for="(user,index) in users" v-bind:key="index">
                <div class=" card-body">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src={{user.avatar}}>
                    </img>
                    <h1>
                        {{user.first_name}} + {{user.last_name}}
                    </h1>
                    <p>
                        {{user.email}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const {
            createApp
        } = Vue

        createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    users: []
                }
            },
            methods: {
                loadUsers() {
                    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=10').then(res =>res.json()).then(data =>users = (data.data));

                }
            },
            mounted() {

                this.loadUsers()
            }
        },
        ).mount('#usuarios')
    </script>
</body>
```

"
//i tried changing the method loadUsers multiple times. this is the way that dont show errors .
//however still does not work. the goal is to load the array users with the data from the fetch. and use the user in the vue to show the information from users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the component instance you need to references the data and methods by using `this`
(it's not needed in the HTML part because Vue is clever!)

```js
then(data => this.users = (data.data));
```

Make sure you have this script tag to use Vue from a CDN (I assume you have it but it's not on your code!)

Like in the example on the official doc: